# Python PyQt6 confused about method argument -> Union[QBrush, QColor, GlobalColor, int, QGradient]

Tags: python, pyqt6

I have a couple of methods I've come across that ask for a Union.  Such as this `setForeground(Union[QBrush, QColor, GlobalColor, int, QGradient])` from `QStandardItem` and this `backgroundBrush: Union[QBrush, QColor, GlobalColor, int, QGradient]` from `QStyleOptionView`.  There are others.

I don't have code to share because I have not got to that point yet.  I don't understand that argument.  My IDE says that I need to pass a `typing.Union`, but the docs for that say it takes two parameters [Python typing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).  "To define a union, use e.g. Union[int, str] or the shorthand int | str. Using that shorthand is recommended."

So, can someone give me an example of how to successfully pass that argument?  Thanks.

Comment: The Union is a type annotation that says the argument can be any of the types listed in the Union.  In your example, it means you could pass a QBrush to setForeground or a QColor, etc.

Comment: Ooh!  Thanks, @shao.lo

Well, that opens up me wide up.